# Node js error require modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, hummus.js

I created an API including using of hummus.js. After testing it local, I uploaded my new API Build on my Server (Ubuntu Root + Plesk Onyx) and npm install my package.json (with Plesk => Output: Installation complete Status: Success). But my new Build doesn't work. After debugging my Code I detect the error. My API get an Internal Error after require one module (Tested this with that Code)

```
try {
 var hummus = require('hummus');
 var fillClass = require('../classes/fillform').fillForm;
    }
    catch (e) {
    res.send("ERROR HUMMUS")
    }
```

Run this Code I get = ERROR HUMMUS

I thought that the hummus path doesn't exist but with:

```
 try {
      res.send(require.resolve("hummus")).end();
  } catch(e) {
      res.send("not found").end();
      process.exit(e.code);
  }
```

I get the path to the module (hummus). Although all file in this folder exists.

(Other modules like async, fs etc works well)

What I do wrong? What should I do?

Greetings

edit Package.json
  `{"name": "XXX-API",
  "version": "1.0.9",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "archiver": "^2.0.0",
    "array-sum": "^1.0.0",
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "big-integer": "^1.6.24",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "curl": "^0.1.4",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "file-encryptor": "^0.1.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "ftp": "^0.3.10",
    "ftp-client": "^0.2.2",
    "ftps": "^1.1.0",
    "german-tax-id-validator": "^1.0.3",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "hummus": "^1.0.80",
    "ibantools": "^1.3.0",
    "jsftp": "^2.0.0",
    "leading-zeros": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0",
    "node-datetime": "^2.0.0",
    "node-pdffiller": "0.0.7",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "node-zip": "^1.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "pad-right": "^0.2.2",
    "pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "requestify": "^0.2.5",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "slack-node": "^0.1.8",
    "uid": "0.0.2",
    "xmlbuilder": "^9.0.4"
  }
}`

Comment: Can you show us the error object `e` too please?

Comment: Could you post the contents of your package.json file?

Comment: The Object e is empty => {}. Package.json in edit field

Comment: Maybe the exception is not thrown by the first line in the `try` block (the hummus one), but the second one (the fillClass one). Could you check it?

Comment: Try it with (only) hummus block and get the exception.

Comment: Ok i get now this error : Error: Error: /var/www/vhosts/XXX.XXX/api.XXX.XXX/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node: invalid ELF header

Answer (score 0):

Pls write the error to log.

```
... catch (err){
   logger.debug(err.stack)
}
```

No better way than error stack.